# React Native Vertical Slider

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-animatable, react-native-gesture-handler

I am Tring to make a screen in react native in which height of upper view is resizable via dragging from the bottom.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FZIW.png)

Size of (1) increases on dragging (2)

So far I tried two approaches 
1. PanResponder

```
const Chat = (props) => {
  const orders = [
    //Some Array
  ]
  const Height = Dimensions.get('window').height

 const boxHeight = useRef(new Animated.Value(Height / 3)).current
  const panResponder = useRef(PanResponder.create({

    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,

    onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {

      const nextValue = boxHeight+gestureState.dy
      let newVal = nextValue >= maxHeight?maxHeight:nextValue
      newVal = newVal <= minHeight?minHeight:newVal
      boxHeight.setValue(newVal)
    },
  }
)).current;
return (
    <Container>
      <Animated.View style={[{ borderBottomColor: '#ccc', borderBottomWidth: 3 }, { height:boxHeight }]}>
         <FlatList
          data={orders}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => <List item={item} index={index} />}
        />
        <View {...panResponder.panHandlers} style={{backgroundColor:'#000',height:20}}></View >
      </Animated.View>
      <ChatScreen />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

2. Pan-gesture- handler

> ```
> const Chat = (props) => {
>   const orders = [
>     //some array
>   ]
>   const Height = Dimensions.get('window').height
>   const boxHeight = useRef(new Animated.Value(Height / 3)).current
>   const minHeight = 10
>   const maxHeight = Height - 100
>
>   const onPanGestureEvent = (event) => {
>     boxHeight.setValue(
>       Animated.diffClamp(
>         Animated.add(
>           orderBoxHeight, Animated.multiply(
>             event.nativeEvent.translationY, Animated.diffClamp(
>               event.nativeEvent.velocityY, 0, 1
>             )
>           )
>         )
>       ), minHeight, maxHeight
>     )
>   }
>   return (
>     <Container>
>       <Animated.View style={[{ borderBottomColor: '#ccc', borderBottomWidth: 3 }, { height: boxHeight }]}>
>         <FlatList
>           data={orders}
>           renderItem={({ item, index }) => <OrderList item={item} index={index} />}
>         />
>         <PanGestureHandler
>           onGestureEvent={(event) => onPanGestureEvent(event)}
>         >
>           <Animated.View style={{ backgroundColor: '#000', height: 20 }}></Animated.View >
>         </PanGestureHandler>
>       </Animated.View>
>       <ChatScreen />
>     </Container>
>   )
> }
> ```

But none Worked... I have also tried few other variations of both but none of them worked as desired either it slides too fast or does not move at all